# Numeric Get request parameter shows up as zero for some reason

Tags: php, request

I have a test page I am playing around with and maybe it is just too early in the morning, but I seem to be running into something strange:

I have this url:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trip_story.php?hike_id=108

to log in
login: test@comehike.com
password: password

I do this to get the hike_id parameter:

```
$hike_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hike_id']);
$errors = array();
if ( isset ( $hike_id ) && !empty ($hike_id)  )
{
   $errors[] = 'Hike id was empty.  Could not get the hike information';
}
```

But the hike id is 0 as is shown later on the page when I output things to the screen. So since the hike_id is 0, it passes that validation test which is a bug.  Any idea why that would happen since the hike_id that is passed is 108?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a flaw on your logic. what your if statement really asks is this:

"if $hike_id as set, and is not empty, throw an error"

0 *is* [empty](http://php.net/empty) and so your statement wont throw an error. Try with another value, for example 1, and see what happens.

In addition, why do you use mysql_real_escape_string there? Wait with escaping until you use the value in a SQL query. Note that mysql_real_escape_string requires an active connection to the database, otherwise it will return false (which is interpreted as zero in numeric context; maybe that's why 108 is converted to 0?)

Comment: Thanks Emil.  You know I kind of like to escape the parameters early on just to make sure I don't forget to do it lol.

Comment: Also, you can escape an integer input by casting to int rather than using `mysql_real_escape_string()` by doing something like `$hike_id = (int)$_GET['hike_id'];` or `intval($_GET['hike_id']);`.  If there are numbers at the beginning of the value being casted to int, it will preserve them and strip out any characters.  If there are characters at the beginning and numbers at the end, it will strip it all out and leave 0 behind.